Are there geometry nodes to make this possible?

Does there exist a series of geometry nodes, such that:
Object {1} Is the main object but contains the UV map of
Object [2], but contains the object property (shape) of
Object [3]?
I ask this question because of VDM brushes, hoping to find a simpler solution in creating brushes from complex/pre-existing meshes.
The only solution I've managed to work out, is to give [2] a multi-res modifier and a shrinkwrap modifier, and selecting [3] as the target object, and sculpting [2] carefully so that it can have a very similar shape, and then bake the VDM via the add-on. But if anyone knows of a much faster, more streamlined way of achieving this, where I can avoid sculpting altogether, and simply use a geometry node setup, I'd really appreciate it.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
